# Apache Gaucamole : Connection to guacd timed out in EC2 machine

Tags: java, apache, sockets, networking, guacamole

Guacd and Gaucamole client( which connects to Guacd ) are running in the same EC2 machine.

Guacd is running on port 4822.

Gaucamole client(webapp which connects to Guacd) is running on port 8088

I am trying to connect to the Guacd from Gaucamole client through socket connection and its throwing "Connection to guacd timed out".

```
GuacamoleSocket socket = new ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket(new InetGuacamoleSocket(
        "localhost", 4822), config);
```

I have verified that guacd is running properly on port 4822.
But i am not able to connect to it.

Please help!!

Comment: Is the server listening on the local interface? Or on the public interface only. You need to replace "localhost" with the public ip/name in this case.

Comment: They both are running on same EC2 machine. I have tried with providing "localhost" and publicIp as well. Its not working.